How to apply type annotations to variables in a tuple assignment statement?
How should one annotate the types of variables assigned to in a tuple assignment?
As a minimal example:
def foo() -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
  return "x", 2

a, b = foo()

In context, I'm able to provide tighter type bounds on a and b than are automatically derived, and it's desirable to be able to express this in the program in order to better communicate intent and better leverage static analysis and autocompletion tools.
How should one annotate or hint the types of variables assigned to in this type of tuple assignment statement?

Two things that don't work are individual PEP 526 annotations, or one PEP 526 annotation on the tuple being assigned to:
def bar():
  a: str, b: int = foo()
#       ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax

def bar():
  a, b: Tuple[str, int] = foo()
# ^
# SyntaxError: only single target (not tuple) can be annotated

Using a PEP 484 annotation on the statement also doesn't work: At the very least, it's tolerated at runtime, but Pylance doesn't pick up any useful information from it.
def bar():
  a, b = foo() # type: Tuple[str, int]
#                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Pylance: Warning: Type annotation not supported for this statement

One thing that does work is to apply individual PEP 526 annotations to a and b on their own lines:
def bar():
  a: str
  b: int
  a, b = foo()

But that's now three times as many lines.
Is there a way to do this in just one line?
Additionally, as an extra bonus, you can't simply make a 1:1 translation from that to PEP 484 (e.g. for supporting python versions <= 3.5):
def bar():
  a # type: str
# ^
# UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'a' where it is not associated with a value
  b # type: int
  a, b = foo()

As a workaround you can explicitly assign None to make them valid statements:
def bar():
  a = None # type: str
  b = None # type: int
  a, b = foo()

But that introduces a behavioral difference, in that if foo() raises or returns something that can't be unpacked into a and b, then the code ends up leaving them as None in violation of the non-None invariant; if you wanted to leave them unbound you'd need to explicitly delete them if there's an exception:
def bar():
  try:
    a = None # type: str
    b = None # type: int
    a, b = foo()
  except Exception as e:
   del a, b
   raise e

And now that's officially going too far. How can one write a PEP 484 hint for a variable's type without binding that variable?

Another duplicate would be Typehinting an unpack assignment, which goes into more details on how assignment statements and annotated assignment statements come from different parts of Python's grammar.

@Brian61354270 Thank you for finding the duplicate I was starting to refer to in a comment :) (TL;DR Old lookahead restrictions prevented such multiple annotations.)

Actually, the way to do exactly what you asked is a, b = foo() # type: (str, int), which none of the linked answers appear to cover (see mypy playground). However, type comments are deprecated, and will be removed in the future.
